# Tooltip-textbox in C#

Tags: c#, tooltip, show-hide

I have applied a ToolTip to textbox in C# such that the textbox has to accept the name of the user. In the ToolTip, I have types the instructions that only alphabets are welcome in the textbox, which is a success. But what I want is to make that ToolTip disappear when the user starts to type his name or moves to another textbox. The coding so far is;

```
    ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
    String message = "Trying";
    private void txtName_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtName.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            tt.Show(string.Empty, txtName, 0);
            tt.Show(message, txtName, new Point(0, -2 * txtName.Height));
        }
    }
```

Help?

Comment: Why not use a more convenient way of HTML5 `placeholders`. They are a perfect match for your usecase.

Comment: set tt.ShowAlways = false;

Answer (score 0):

There is an event on the textbox called [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). It fires as soon as the `Text` property of the control changes in value. Typing a character does change the `Text` property and therefor triggers the event.

Leveraging that knowledge, you can dismiss the tooltip as soon as `Text` is no longer empty like so:

```
private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctl = (Control) sender;  // sender is a control
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctl.Text))
    {
        tt.SetToolTip(ctl, String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Notice that this implementation can be used generically, by any control that you want to have this behavior.